# Copy content of a file to multiple files using CAT command in UNIX

Tags: unix

I have 3 files
File1, File2, File3
I want to copy the content of File1 to File2 and File3 in a single command
Is it possible with CAT command
If yes how, if no then which command is used to do this task

Answer (score 0):

maybe this code can help you.

```
cat file1.txt >> file2.txt && cat file1.txt >> file3.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `tee`:

```
$ cat file1 | tee file2 > file3
```

`man tee`:

```
NAME
       tee - read from standard input and write to standard output and files
```